# scala: strategy to define mock objects, injecting dependencies using implicits

Tags: scala, testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I have a Social object, responsable of connecting to Twitter, facebook, etc, and retrieve provider info for the specified user

For each provider I implemented a singleton TwitterAdapter, all inheriting from an abstract class SocialAdapter

here's the code: https://github.com/RestOpenGov/ideas-ba/blob/master/webservice/app/services/security/SocialConnector.scala#L98

For testing, I would obviously like to mock the TwitterAdapter, so that instead of connecting with twitter it returns some fixed response.

One solution I've found was to inject the list of adapters using an implicit parameter. The problem with this solution is that the Social.retrieveSocialProviderInfo is called from other functions, so I have to pass around the implicit List[SocialAdapter] parameter though all the call chain, like this:

```
def createApplicationToken(accessToken: AccessToken)
  (implicit adapters: List[SocialAdapter] = Social.defaultAdapters)
: Either[List[Error], ApplicationToken] = {

  // go to social info provider and fetch information
  retrieveProviderInfo(accessToken).fold(
  [...]

def retrieveProviderInfo(accessToken: AccessToken)
  (implicit adapters: List[SocialAdapter] = Social.defaultAdapters)
: Either[List[Error], IdentityProviderInfo] = {
[...]
```

and finally

```
object Social {

  val defaultAdapters = List(TwitterAdapter, FacebookAdapter)

  def retrieveSocialProviderInfo
    (accessToken: AccessToken)
    (implicit adapters: List[SocialAdapter] = Social.defaultAdapters)   // adapters can be injected
  : Option[IdentityProviderInfo] = {
  [...]
```

You get the idea

It works fine, normally I just ignore the second group of parameters and pick the default from Social.defaultAdapters, I only set it to List(MockTwitterAdapter, MockFacebookAdapter) when testing, but I'm cluttering the code just to be able to test it.

The other solution would be to make Social.defaultAdapters a var (instead of a val) and just change it for testing, normally in production mode it would always have the same value.

I think this must be a pretty common scenario. Is there a better strategy to handle these situations? Or maybe some way to extend the scope of the implicit assignment? Or shall I just go with a full-featured dependency injection framework?

Answer (score 6):

A simple approach can be to just use traits all along:

```
// you can test this trait and override the adapters as you wish
// by overriding the defaultAdapters member
trait Social {

  implicit val defaultAdapters = List(TwitterAdapter, FacebookAdapter)

  def retrieveSocialProviderInfo(accessToken: AccessToken):
    Option[IdentityProviderInfo] = ...
}

// you can use this object directly in your production code
// if you don't want to mix it in
object Social extends Social

// or use the trait by mixing it with another
trait Application extends Social {
  def createApplicationToken(accessToken: AccessToken): 
    Either[List[Error], ApplicationToken] = {
    // the defaultAdapters are accessible to the 
    // retrieveProviderInfo method 
    retrieveProviderInfo(accessToken).fold(...)
  }
```